# Does the Riemann-Christoffel curvature determine the connection?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am looking for the integrability condition of the following system of pde:

$$\partial_{[\nu}\Gamma^\kappa_{\mu]\lambda}+\Gamma^\kappa_{[\nu|\rho|}\Gamma^\rho_{\mu]\lambda}=\frac{1}{2}R_{\mu\nu\lambda}{}^{\kappa},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$

given sufficiently smooth functions $R_{\mu\nu\lambda}{}^{\kappa}$ on some smooth manifold $M^n$, with $R_{(\mu\nu)\lambda}{}^{\kappa}=0$. This equation is the definition of the Riemann-Christoffel curvature of a *given* connection $\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}$. But I am interested in the reverse questions:

1. *Given functions $R_{\mu\nu\lambda}{}^{\kappa}$, with $R_{(\mu\nu)\lambda}{}^{\kappa}=0$, what are the conditions such that they form the compoments of the Riemann-Christoffel curvature of some connection?*
2. *If the given functions $R_{\mu\nu\lambda}{}^{\kappa}$ do satisfy those integrability conditions, then what will be general form of the connection coefficients $\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}$?* (When $R_{\mu\nu\lambda}{}^{\kappa}=0$, it is well-known that there exists an invertible matrix field $[A_{\mu\nu}]$ (with inverse $[A^{\mu\nu}]$) such that $\Gamma^\gamma_{\mu\nu}=A^{\gamma\lambda}\partial_{\nu} A_{\lambda\mu}$.)

In Schouten (Chapter III, equation 5.19), it is stated that the integrability condition of (1) are given by the Bianchi identities

$$\nabla_{[\omega}R_{\mu\nu]\lambda}{}^\kappa=2S_{[\omega\nu}{}^\sigma\, R_{\mu]\sigma\lambda}{}^\kappa,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)$$
where $S_{\mu\nu}{}^\kappa$ is the torsion of the connection $\Gamma^\kappa_{\mu\nu}$.

It is clear that (2) involves covarient derivative  wirh respect to the connection $\Gamma$ and also the torsion $S$ of $\Gamma$, but to start with no such $\Gamma$ is given. We are *looking for* such a $\Gamma$. I fail to understand in what sense, (2) is an integrability condition of (1). I'm also not sure, whether to determine a $\Gamma$ satisfying (1), some (skew-symmetric) functions $S_{\mu\nu}{}^\lambda$ should also be given *a priori* so that the desired connection has also these specified fuctions as its torsion.

**Notes:** 1. No metric structure is given on the manifold $M^n$.

2. It would be great if it can be answered at least for $n=3$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://eudml.org/doc/74779

Comment: For the connections with torsion the question gets easier.

Comment: Dear Dr. @DeaneYang, what I understand from the referred paper is that as long as the structure group G of the bundle is abelian, for $n=3$ the Bianchi identities are the necessary and sufficient conditions for local solvability of $\Gamma$ from the equation $Curv(\Gamma)=F$. Am I correct? If yes, then I have a little doubt: is the matrix of 1-forms appearing in the Bianchi identities of a given 2-form $F$ (which, we are enquiring, whether or not is a curvature form of $\Gamma$)same as the connection form $\Gamma$? How can it be a priori specified?

Comment: The question "http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73439/when-is-a-given-matrix-of-two-forms-a-curvature-form?rq=1" deals with the exactly same enquiry which I recently discovered. Dr. Bryant has given an example here for $n=4$ when there is no solution $\Gamma$ to $Curv(\Gamma)=F$. I am curious about the "pseudo"-Bianchi identities mentioned in this question. As far as I am able to understand, pseudo Bianchi identity is a Bianchi type identity with *any* matrix of one form $\Gamma$, not necessarily the connection form $\Gamma$ which we are seeking. Am I correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of the difficulty in providing an answer to your question is the fact that the expression "the integrability condition" is a somewhat vague notion, and it's used in slightly different senses in different contexts.

The usual, somewhat imprecise, sense is that, for a given system of PDE, its 'integrability condition' is the set of necessary and sufficient conditions that it have local solutions.  Slightly more precise usage would be, given a PDE system that depends on some data (in your case, the equations (1), where the data is the curvature $R$), to find the necessary and sufficient conditions *on the data* that ensure that the PDE system have local solutions.

In this sense, the Bianchi identities (your equation (2)) are usually not *the* integrability condition for the system (1) but are only *part* of the integrability condition, and they have to be interpreted appropriately.  The point is that, when $R$ is specified, equation (2) is an *algebraic* equation $\Gamma$ must satisfy if it is to satisfy the first order PDE system (1).  [It may not be immediately apparent that (2) is an algebraic equation on $\Gamma$, but if you look at the definition of $\nabla$, you'll see that the left hand side of (2) only involves the unknown coefficients of $\Gamma$ linearly with no differentiation of them, and the right hand side involves the unknown $S$, which is computed linearly from the unknown $\Gamma$.]  Thus, a necessary condition *on the data $R$* that (1) have a solution is that there be at least one solution $\overline\Gamma$ to the inhomogeneous linear algebraic system (2) (whose coefficients come from $R$ and its first derivatives).  Generally, this necessary condition is *not* sufficient, though, as examples in dimensions $4$ and above show.

However, what Deane Yang's reference eudml.org/doc/74779 (DeTurck & Talvacchia, 1987) shows is that, when (i) $n=3$, (ii) $R$ is sufficiently generic (in an appropriate sense) while satisfying the integrability condition (2), *and* (iii) $R$ is real-analytic, then the system (1) is locally solvable.  The system of PDE for $\Gamma$ that has to be solved, though, is highly nonlinear and, in a sense, overdetermined, so that the Cartan-Kähler Theorem or one of its modern versions has to be applied.  There is no uniqueness and no way explicitly to solve the equations for $\Gamma$ for a given generic $R$ that satisfies the integrability condition.  In that sense, your second 'reverse question' has no good answer.

Finally, let me remark that one *could* conceivably want to answer the more restrictive problem of specifying *both* the curvature $R$ and torsion $S$ of a connection $\Gamma$ on a manifold $M$.  This problem is overdetermined even when $n=3$ and, generally, has no solution.  This problem also has an additional set of integrability conditions of the form $\nabla S = F(R,S)$ (for an explicit expression $F(R,S)$ that one can write down easily) and which are also inhomogeneous linear algebraic in $\Gamma$, in addition to the Bianchi conditions $\nabla R = G(R,S)$ that you already have written down as (2).  In general, these combined integrability conditions are *not* sufficient for the generic pair $(S,R)$ that satisfy them in order for a solution $\Gamma$ to exist.

Comment: Dear Prof. Bryant, thank you so much for this clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a partial answer (the solution is found with some additional restrictions)
is given in the paper http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00759087 (Determination of the metric from the curvature, by Hernando Quevedo)

P.S. Of course Deane Yang's answer/comment above is more relevant for your question. If you not already found it, see also http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021782409001317 (The prescribed curvature problem in dimension four, by J.M. Masqué, L.M. Pozo Coronado and I. Sánchez Rodríguez).

Comment: Thanks. There are few articles and discussions in this website on determination of the metric given a curvature tensor. But I my question is different. In my case, there is no metric structure on the manifold and I am not looking for one. I just want the connection, given its Riemann-Christoffel curvature.

Comment: But, as an intermediate step, the author obtains connection coefficients and tetrad vectors solely in terms of supposed curvature tensor (equation (2) in the paper).