# Prescribed curvature problem of a connection beyond the real analytic category for $SL(3,R)$ bundles?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

With reference to the questions [Does the Riemann-Christoffel curvature determine the connection?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207266/does-the-riemann-christoffel-curvature-determine-the-connection) and [When is a given matrix of two forms a curvature form?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73439/when-is-a-given-matrix-of-two-forms-a-curvature-form?rq=1%22), and recalling the following important result stated in Theorem 7 in "J C Talvacchia. Prescribing the curvature of a principal bundle connection. University of Pennsylvania, 1989.
PhD thesis, Dissertations available from ProQuest. Paper AAI9004831.
http://repository.upenn.edu/dissertations/AAI9004831.":

"Let $P$ be an $SL(3,\mathbb{R})$-bundle over a three dimensional base manifold. Then a generic analytic $sl(3,\mathbb{R})$-valued two form is locally the curvature form of connection on $P$.",

I would like to ask if there is any extension of this particular result (i.e., existence of a connection over an $SL(3,\mathbb{R})$-bundle with three dimensional base manifold whose curvature form is a given $sl(3,\mathbb{R})$-valued two form) beyond real analytic category?

Thanks in advance!